# C# - import class from third-party library and make it a derived class (or something similar)

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, derived

I'm a beginner in C#. I would like to import a class from a third-party library and make it a derived class (or something similar). In the following example, how can I create a class that can have both CircleSpecificMethods() and CommonShapeMethods()?

Thanks!

Third-party library:

```
namespace ThirdPartyLib
{
    public class Circle
    {
        public CircleSpecificMethods()
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    public class Triangle
    {
        public TriangleSpecificMethods()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

My Program:

```
using ThirdPartyLib;
namespace MyProgram
{
    public class Shape
    {
        public CommonShapeMethods()
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    public class Rectangle : Shape
    {
        public RectangleSpecificMethods()
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var rectangle = new Rectangle();
            var circle = new Circle();

            rectangle.CommonShapeMethods();
            rectangle.RectangleSpecificMethods();

            circle.CommonShapeMethods(); // How can I make circle to have CommonShapeMethods as well?
            circle.CircleSpecificMethods();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ask for is the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Adapter is an auxiliary class that lets you adapt a class into another class. In your example that would be

```
// adapter fulfills your requirement, it is a shape
public class CircleToShapeAdapter : Shape 
{
     private Circle _circle { get; set; }

     // but it takes their object as a source
     public CircleToShapeAdapter( Circle circle )
     {
         this._circle = circle;
     }

     // for any method that is required by your Shape specification
     // you just find a way to implement the method using their API
     public void ShapeMethod()
     {
         circle.DoSomething();
     }
}
```

and then you can have your shapes using their circles

```
Shape shape = new CircleToShapeAdapter( circle );
```

Note that the adapter can still expose circle specific methods but it won't act as a circle (won't inherit from it) as C# doesn't let you derive from two classes. This means that either their base class or yours has to be an interface instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change your 3rd party to inherit from `Shape` then you can't do it. You also can't inherit from 2 different classes (see the [Deadly Diamond of Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)).

If you MUST do something close to it try changing `Shape` to an [Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) and create a new class which will inherit from `Circle` and will also implement your interface